# how to pass latitude and longitude to google maps API in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm still new in Google Maps API and I have difficulty to pass latitude and longitude from first activity to second activity. 
Now when I click a button in first activity, it will pass latitude and longitude value to a second activity that contains a google map.

First Activity :

```
apotek.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            double lat = -7.94203712;
    double lng = 112.60936975;
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Menu1.this, menu_cari.class);
    bundle.putDouble(menu_cari.TAG1,lat);
    bundle.putDouble(menu_cari.TAG2, lng);
    startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Second Activity :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (GoogleServicesAvailable()) {
        Toast.makeText(menu_cari.this, "Terhubung...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu_cari);
        initmap();
    } else {
        //maps tidak ditampilkan
    }
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    lat_apotek=extras.getDouble(TAG1,0);
    lng_apotek=extras.getDouble(TAG2,0);
    goToLocation(lat_apotek,lng_apotek,20);
}
public void goToLocation(double lat, double lng, float zoom) {
    LatLng ll = new LatLng(lat, lng);
    CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll, zoom);
    mGoogleMap.moveCamera(update);
}
```

Comment: is latitude and longitude you are receiving in second activity is 0 or not ?

Comment: so what is ur question or problem?

Comment: @JiteshDalsaniya yeah bro, it shown 0 and sometimes it force close the apps

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 i cant receive the latitude and longitude value in second activity

Comment: then you should put validation first for checking lat and lng is not zero and also check for LatLng object for null. put required validation may be that is solve your problem.

Comment: check the answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forget to put extras in bundle:

```
  Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
Intent intent = new Intent(Menu1.this, menu_cari.class);
bundle.putDouble(menu_cari.TAG1,lat);
bundle.putDouble(menu_cari.TAG2, lng);
intent.putExtras(bundle);  //add this
```

Also u should call `goToLocation(lat_apotek,lng_apotek,20);` in `onMapReady` method

Also check the tag:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
lat_apotek=extras.getDouble(TAG1,0);  //TAG1 should match `menu_cari.TAG1`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
apotek.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            double lat = -7.94203712;
    double lng = 112.60936975;
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Menu1.this, menu_cari.class);
    bundle.putDouble(menu_cari.TAG1,lat);
    bundle.putDouble(menu_cari.TAG2, lng);
    // add this line to put an existing bundle into the intents
    // you may also conside intent.putExtra() and getIntent().getDouble() in second activity
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: You should explain your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
FirstActivity: 


    apotek.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            double lat = -7.94203712;
    double lng = 112.60936975;
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Menu1.this, menu_cari.class);
    bundle.putDouble(menu_cari.TAG1,lat);
    bundle.putDouble(menu_cari.TAG2, lng);

///////////////////////////////
    intent.putExtra("bundleKey",bundle);
/////////////////////

    startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

For Bundle access :

```
Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();
double lng=b.getDouble(key);
```